# Is the converse of $\bmod p$ method in determining Galois group true? Or is there a prime corresponding to every member of the Galois group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

We have the following mod $p$ technique to detemine the Galois group of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$:

> Assume $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible, $p$ is a prime,
> and $\bar{f}$ is the polynomial obtained by $f$ mod $p$.
> (Or more precisely, $\bar{f}$ is the image of the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[x]\to F_p[x]$,
> induced by $\pi:  \mathbb{Z}\to F_p$).
> If $\bar{f}$ is separable over $F_p$ and it factors in $F_p$ into irreducible polynomials as $f=f_1\cdots f_l$,
> with ${\rm deg}f_i=d_i$, then ${\rm Gal}(f,\mathbb Q)$ contains a permutation
> which is the product of $l$ disjoint cycles, each with length $d_1,\cdots,d_l$.

I wonder is the converse true? Or, if ${\rm Gal}(f,\mathbb Q)$ contains a permutation
which is the product of $l$ disjoint cycles, each with length $d_1,\cdots,d_l$,
then does there always exist a prime $p$, s.t. the corresponding $\bar{f}$ is separable over $F_p$
and it factors in $F_p$ into irreducible polynomials as $f=f_1\cdots f_l$, with ${\rm deg}f_i=d_i$?
If this is incorrect for the identity element, then is it correct for the non-identity elements in ${\rm Gal}(f,\mathbb Q)$?

(Attempt: For the simplest case $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$ and the identity element in $S_2$, it is equivalent to determine if exists $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ and $p$ prime s.t. $u+v\equiv a \mod p$ and $uv\equiv b \mod p$.
This already seems hard for me.)

Comment: Yes, every element of $G$ can be detected this way, and even more can be said. See [here](https://timomath.com/dedekinds-theorem-on-galois-groups-and-chebotarevs-density-theorem/) for example.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks for your comment! This is quite helpful.